# How to use `std::is_enum` with unnamed `enum`s?

Tags: c++, types, enums, constraints, type-traits

The title is pretty much self explanatory. Here is my situation:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

class C1{
    enum{
        c1 = 3
    }
}

class C2{
    enum{
        c2 = 10
    }
}

template<class C>
class C3{
    void do_this();
    void do_that();

    void foo(){
        if constexpr(std::is_enum<C::c1>::value){
            do_this();
        }
        if constexpr(std::is_enum<C::c2>::value){
            do_that();
        }
    }
}
```

If I'd try to compile this I'd get the error

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class _Tp> struct std::is_enum’
note: expected a type, got ‘typename C::c1’

error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class _Tp> struct std::is_enum’
note: expected a type, got ‘typename C::c2’
```

So hence my question: is it possible to use `std::is_enum` with unnamed `enum`s?

Comment: In your example you could probably just use a switch statement

Comment: Clean compile needs 2 `typename` and a bunch of `;`'s fixing - https://godbolt.org/z/aYWrT6MPK

Comment: Unrelated: You have incorrectly put `;` after `c1=3` and `c2=10`.

Comment: @RichardCritten - Try instantiating the template. It's not "clean" until two phase lookup is actually done.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso but wouldn't that also give an error if I tried to access `c1` for example and the class passed to the template was `C2`?

Comment: @JoséEduardoBueno, you're right, I missed the intention of the code here

Comment: @José - What do you want to happen here? You want the value of something compared to those constants, or types to be examined? It's not "pretty much self explanatory".

Comment: @RichardCritten The program will be ill formed if you try to instantiate the template given in your solution.

Comment: @StoryTeller I'm trying to detect which type was passed to my template in `C3` based on whether a given key exists or not in an unnamed `enum`. Of course this is just a toy example. My real case is more complex

Comment: @RichardCritten if I add `typename`s to my real case I get errors like `no type named c1 in C1`

Comment: @JoséEduardoBueno You can use `decltype`.

Comment: @JasonLiam would you mind telling me how? This is my first time working with type traits and SFINAE-like stuff

Comment: @JoséEduardoBueno See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jWhj1zvYM). Modify it according to your requirements. Should i add it as an answer?

Comment: @JoséEduardoBueno I solved it using SFINAE. See [working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/K9bjdnfdh). Also check out my updated [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74129648/12002570). It will work according to your requirements. This has the advantage that it will work with c++11 as well so you don't have to use `if constexpr` of `c++17`.  See [C++ 11 working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ch1Mvbsvz)

Comment: Alex: You offered a 500 rep bounty _"to draw more attention to this question"_ but it's not clear what you expect from it since there are already good answers. Well, now there's a new good one, but, are you expecting something revolutionary different?

Comment: @TedLyngmo By more attention I thought that this question will be more easily searchable in search engines like google. Also I do think that this question(and its answers) deserves much more views/attention.

Comment: @Alex Ok, if that was your goal, it was a success. One more good answer appeared :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### C++11 using SFINAE

You can use `decltype` to get the type associated with `c1` and `c2` and then use *SFINAE* as shown below . [C++11 Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ofsbW1a76):

```
struct C1{
    enum{
        c1 = 3
    };
};

struct C2{
    enum{
        c2 = 10
    };
};

template<class C>
class C3{
    void do_this(){std::cout << "do this called" << std::endl;}
    void do_that(){std::cout << "do that called " << std::endl;}
public:
    //overload for calling do_this
    template<typename T = C,typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, C1>::value, bool>::type = std::is_enum<decltype(T::c1)>::value >void foo()
    {
        do_this();
    }
    //overload for calling do_that
    template<typename T = C,typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, C2>::value, bool>::type = std::is_enum<decltype(T::c2)>::value >void foo()
    {
        do_that();
    }
    //overload when none of the conditions are satisfied
    template<typename... T>
    void foo(T...)
    {
        std::cout <<"ellipsis called " << std::endl;
    }
     
};
int main()
{
    C3<C1> c1;
    c1.foo();     //calls do_this() using #1

    C3<C2> c2;
    c2.foo();     //calls do_that() using #2

    C3<int> c3;
    c3.foo();    //calls the ellipsis version
    
}
```

See also [C++ 17 demo](https://godbolt.org/z/r8xGhzv3P) version that uses `std::enable_if_t` and `std::is_same_v` and `std::is_enum_v`.

---

##### C++20 using concept

```
struct C1{
    enum{
        c1 = 3
    };
};
template<typename T>
concept enumC1 = std::is_same_v<T, C1>;

struct C2{
    enum{
        c2 = 10
    };
};
template<typename T>
concept enumC2 = std::is_same_v<T, C2>;

template<class C>
class C3{
    void do_this(){std::cout << "do this called" << std::endl;}
    void do_that(){std::cout << "do that called " << std::endl;}
public:
    //overload when none of the conditions are satisfied
    template<typename T = C>
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout <<"general called " << std::endl;
    }
    //overload for calling do_this
    template<enumC1 T = C>void foo()
    {
        do_this();
    }
    //overload for calling do_that
    template<enumC2 T = C>void foo()
    {
        do_that();
    }
    
     
};
int main()
{
    C3<C1> c1;
    c1.foo();     //calls do_this()

    C3<C2> c2;
    c2.foo();     //calls do_that()

    C3<int> c3;
    c3.foo();    //calls the general version
    
}
```

[C++ 20 demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fT8xssf5r)

Comment: `C3<C2>{}.foo();` won't compile. Not sure if OP cares.

Comment: Hello. I do care

Comment: As I mentioned in a previous comment, I would like to detect which type/class was passed to my templated class based on these enums

Comment: @Jason thanaks for the answer anyway

Comment: @JoséEduardoBueno You're welcome. I am trying to modify the program to meet your requirements. If i do, i will update the code.

Comment: @JasonLiam take a look at the comment I wrote to the other answer. Perhaps that can help you have a better idea of what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: @JoséEduardoBueno Finally after thinking about the requirements, i solved it using SFINAE. See [working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/K9bjdnfdh). Also check out the updated answer. It will work according to your requirements.

Answer (score 5):

It is absolutely possible to use [`std::is_enum`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_enum) with unnamed enums.

There are just 2 problems that need to be fixed in your current implementation:

- `std::is_enum<C::c1>::value` - `C::c1` is a data member, but [`std::is_enum`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_enum) expects a type template parameter.
  => you need to use [`decltype(...)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) here, e.g. `std::is_enum<decltype(C::c1)>::value`
- `C::c1` will cause a substitution failure if `C` doesn't have a member called `c1`.
  The only way around this is to do this in a context where substition failures doesn't result in your program being ill-formed.
  So you can either use SFINAE or (if C++20 is available) a [requires-expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/requires).

---

So with C++20 this would work:

[godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/T1ds7Y4hM)

```cpp
template<class T>
concept is_enum_value = std::is_enum_v<T>;

template<class C>
struct C3 {
    void foo() {
        if constexpr(requires { { C::c1 } -> is_enum_value; }) {
            do_this();
        }
        if constexpr(requires { { C::c2 } -> is_enum_value; }) {
            do_that();
        }
    }

    // ...
};
```

If `C::c1` and `C::c2` are mutually exclusive (i.e. every class `C` has either `c1` or `c2` or neither of them - but never both `c1` and `c2` at the same time) you might consider overloading `foo` with [trailing requires-clauses](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints#Requires_clauses) instead.

[godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/hv64YfjrP)

```cpp
template<class C>
struct C3 {
    void foo() requires requires { { C::c1 } -> is_enum_value; } {
        // do_this implementation
    }
    void foo() requires requires { { C::c2 } -> is_enum_value; } {
        // do_that implementation
    }
};
```

---

If C++20 is not available you'd need to use SFINAE, which is a bit more cumbersome:

[godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/cza1M93ba)

```cpp
template<class T, class = void>
constexpr bool has_c1 = false;
template<class T>
constexpr bool has_c1<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<decltype(T::c1)>>> = true;

template<class T, class = void>
constexpr bool has_c2 = false;
template<class T>
constexpr bool has_c2<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<decltype(T::c2)>>> = true; 

template<class C>
struct C3 {
    void foo() {
        if constexpr(has_c1<C>) {
            do_this();
        }
        if constexpr(has_c2<C>) {
            do_that();
        }
    }

    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You should probably name the them both the same thing so the template works with both of them:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <type_traits>

struct C1 {
    enum { c = 3 };
};

struct C2 {
    static constexpr int c = 10;
};

template <class C>
void foo() {
    if constexpr (std::is_enum_v<decltype(C::c)>) {
        std::puts("::c is an enum");
    } else {
        std::puts("::c is not an enum");
    }
}

int main() {
    foo<C1>();
    foo<C2>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this is exactly the problem in my real case: I have a templated class which can take two classes as template arguments. Both these classes have unnamed enums but with different tag names...

Comment: @JoséEduardoBueno does this help: https://godbolt.org/z/vh38KMx3r

Answer (score 1):

There are also good answers, but I'll give another variation for C++20:

```
if constexpr(requires { requires std::is_enum_v<decltype((C::c1))>; }) { /*...*/ }
```

This uses a nested requirement instead of a compound requirement with a type-constraint as in the answer by @Turtlefight. The nested requirement fails if substitution into the expression results in an invalid type or expression and also fails if the expression isn't a constant expression of type `bool` that evaluates to `true`. This should functionally behave the same though.

The additional parentheses in `decltype` are necessary and the compound statement used in the other answer also implicitly uses `decltype` this way to determined the type of the expression.

Without it, `decltype` would produce a non-reference type for a data member of enumeration type (rather than an enumerator's name) and succeed, e.g.

```
class C2{
    static enum {
        c2 = 10
    } c1;
}
```

would succeed both the test for `c1` and `c2` instead of only the one for `c2`.